# Geoserver WFS Layer in OL3 tilted and mirrored

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I am using Geoserver (2.4.2) to display a WFS-Layer in Ol3 (3.13.0). I successfully used this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/b4xtz3cf/) from a fellow user to get things going. Here is my modified code. I am sorry for not providing a fiddle since my Geoserver ist not accessible from the outside.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./ol.css" />
    <style>
      html, body {
          background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="./jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./ol.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        .map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="laodingcont"></div>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
                sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
            loader: function (extent) {
                //place here any actions on start loading layer
                document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='orange'>start loading.....</font>";
                $.ajax('http://IP:PORT/geoserver/namespace/ows', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        service: 'WFS',
                        version: '1.1.0',
                        request: 'GetFeature',
                        typename: 'namespace:landmass_buffer',
                        outputFormat: 'application/json',
                        srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
                        bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326'
                    }
                }).done(loadFeatures)
                    .fail(function () {
                    //place here any actions on fail loading layer
                    document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='red'>error loading vector layer.</font>";
                });
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
        });

        function loadFeatures(response) {
            format = new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            sourceVector.addFeatures(format.readFeatures(response));
            document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='green'>finish loading vector layer.</font>";
        }

        layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: sourceVector,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
                    width: 2
                })
            })
        });

        var lyr_noaalandmasssmplsngl = new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                          url: "http://IP:PORT/geoserver/namespace/wms",
                          params: {"LAYERS": "landmass", "TILED": "true"},
                        })),
                        title: "Landmass"
                      });

        console.log(layerVector.getSource().getFeatures().length);
        map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [lyr_noaalandmasssmplsngl, layerVector],
            target: document.getElementById('map'),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [9, 53],
                maxZoom: 19,
                zoom: 3,
                projection: 'EPSG:4326'
            })
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is a tilted and mirrored WFS layer ontop a WMS layer that is displayed ok. See pic

[image: OL3 WFS layer tilted]

I checked both layers in QGIS to make sure both layers are actually OK and not tilted in any way. When I change the $.ajax GET-Parameter outputFormat to 'application/json' and inside the function loadFeatures format = new ol.format.GeoJSON() everything looks as it is supposed to. See pic

[image: OL3 WFS layer via JSON ok]

So I wonder if this is an error with my code, Openlayers or Geoserver error?

Comment: your client and server are in disagreement as to lat/lon and lon/lat axis order. I can't recall which one GeoServer 2.4.2 used or which one Leaflet uses but you need to change one. try using urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! Funny however that this disagreement only happenens when using pretty straight standardised GML. With GeoJSON both seem to agree on lat/lon order. I'm sorry, but where exact do I try the URN you posted?

Comment: Sorry,  see my own answer (which I can't seem to get deleted). Where exactly do I use the URN?

Comment: GeoJSON and computer scientists believe  that all coordinates must be lon/lat regardless of what they should be. The rest of the geographic world believes that coordinates should always be lat/lon. GML (and WMS-1.3.0) got caught in the middle. You'll need to read the leaflet docs to see how to specify SRS and/or axis order.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try checking the OL3 docs for this issue (since I'm using Openlayers not Leaflet). Btw,  which Stack-forum is the goto place for OL3 question,  this one or stackoverflow.com? I always seem to land here while googling.  I'm not sure but I think the Ol3 devs are linking to stackoverflow..

Comment: It depends if it is a GIS question (like this one) then here if it is a programming issue then SO - I'd expect the relevant devs to watch both :-)